# Load cannot find file using JLD2 in Julia

Tags: julia

I have been using JLD2 in Julia for a while and I recently upgraded to Julia 1.1

Since then I am having trouble with loading my data using JLD2.

Load how I used to do does not work anymore :

```
exp=load("TheCompletePathToTheFile/NameOfTheFile.jld2")
```

I get the following error :

> Error encountered while loading "\u200e\u2068TheCompletePathToTheFile/NameOfTheFile.jld2". 
>   Fatal error: ERROR: SystemError: opening file
>   "\u200e\u2068TheCompletePathToTheFile/NameOfTheFile.jld2": No such
>   file or directory
>
> Stacktrace:
>   [1] handle_error(::SystemError, ::File{DataFormat{:JLD2}}) at
>   /.../.julia/packages/FileIO/YJO7Z/src/error_handling.jl:80
>
> [2] handle_exceptions(::Array{Any,1}, ::String) at
>   /.../.julia/packages/FileIO/YJO7Z/src/error_handling.jl:75
>
> [3] #load#27(::Base.Iterators.Pairs{Union{},Union{},Tuple{},NamedTuple{(),Tuple{}}},
>   ::Function, ::File{DataFormat{:JLD2}}) at
>   /..../.julia/packages/FileIO/YJO7Z/src/loadsave.jl:193
>
> [4]  load(::File{DataFormat{:JLD2}}) at
>   /..../.julia/packages/FileIO/YJO7Z/src/loadsave.jl:172
>
> [5] #load#13(::Base.Iterators.Pairs{Union{},Union{},Tuple{},NamedTuple{(),Tuple{}}},
>   ::Function, ::String) at
>   /..../.julia/packages/FileIO/YJO7Z/src/loadsave.jl:118
>
> [6] load(::String) at
>   /.../.julia/packages/FileIO/YJO7Z/src/loadsave.jl:118  [7] top-level
>   scope at none:0

This :  `load("TheCompletePathToTheFile/NameOfTheFile.jld2")` works, but not if I give it a name apparently.

Now if I do

```
cd("CompletePAthToTheFile")
```

`exp=load("NameOfTheFile.jld2")`

I get the same error message but

```
load("NameOfTheFile.jld2")
```

works.

So it seems to be a problem of assigning it to a name but it usually worked and I can't find anywhere in the documentation that anything about this has changed neither on the web about similar error..

I already updated all packages, rm and added again FileIO and JLD2.

Any idea?

Thanks

Comment: It'd be great if you could provide a minimal working example. Generally the philosophy of JLD2 from what I understand is to assign variable names from the `.jld2` file itself, you therefore wouldn't bind the results of load to a name.

Comment: It is now back to working normally, so I just assumed that it was one of Julia's instabilities...  is that a realistic interpretation?  I am not sure how to clarify the question better... sorry :/